# How can i get a value from a search box the box is auto complete one

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a search-box when I type some key words it will auto complete the action.
For example : When i search 'AUS' the result Australia is automatically fills but when I play the suite the box is not filling the data.

SS1

[image]

The above image shows the example when I click on the result it will appear in the 'From' box also recorded.

SS2
[image]

After playing the suite i got the result like this,

SS3

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tim Vanderzeil , but I'm using selenium ide with a version of 3.4.4

Comment: i just done with Katalon studio